# MySQL 2 left joins and no data returned

Tags: mysql, left-join

I use the following SQL to get a some keys I want to translate:

```
SELECT * FROM translate_keys 

LEFT JOIN translations 

ON translate_keys.id = translations.translate_key_id 

LEFT JOIN  languages 

ON languages.id = translations.language_id 

WHERE languages.is_default = 1;
```

If translations for a key is empty I get no results back (languages has content)! I understand that this is because languages get no relation with translations. What can I do? I thought that left join was enough!

Comment: Could you please setup an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `WHERE` condition `languages.is_default = 1`. This eliminates all the dummy records added by the left join, because `languages.is_default` is `NULL` if a translation does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You are joining in the wrong direction. You want the Language table to be your master table. Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM languages  
  LEFT JOIN translations ON languages.id = translations.language_id 
  LEFT JOIN translate_keys ON translate_keys.id = translations.translate_key_id 
WHERE languages.is_default = 1;
```

Or if you're attempting to return all the keys and are receiving no results, it's because of your WHERE criteria -- as @Oswald correctly points out, move that to your JOIN and you should get records (obviously without translations or languages):

```
SELECT * 
FROM translate_keys 
   LEFT JOIN translations ON translate_keys.id = translations.translate_key_id 
   LEFT JOIN  languages ON languages.id = translations.language_id AND languages.is_default = 1;
```

Comment: Your SQL is correct but i need to view the list of keys. Thanx for your time!